# Background page function not triggered in google chrome:

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using the following code to access the background page function in google chrome

**popup.html**

```
function sendRequest(ea,eb)
{
console.log("Inside");
chrome.extension.sendRequest({ea:ea,eb:eb},
        function(response)
        {
            alert(response.farewell);

        });    
}
```

**background.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  })
</html>
</body>
</script>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/"],

      "js": ["popup.js"]
    }
  ],



  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "mine.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs","http://*/","background"

  ],
   "web_accessible_resources": ["loading.html","bu.png"] 


 }
```

However it does not print the alert. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have other listeners as well? If you have multiple listeners only the first one send a response will be used, the others will be ignored

Comment: Can you post your manifest.json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML for background.html is extremely malformed and should be fixed;

```html
<html>
<body>
<script>
  chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tags should be closed in the reverse order of them being open to maintain a correct hierarchy. Since you had not done so, the `<script>` element was malformed and contained invalid syntax `</html></body>` so would not be executed correctly.

Since you're using [version 2](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifestVersion.html) of the manifest you may want to consider abstracting the contents of this script element (ignoring all HTML) to its own file (e.g. background.js) and change your manifest to the following;

```js
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "18",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/"],

      "js": ["popup.js"]
    }
  ],



  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "mine.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs","http://*/","background"

  ],
   "web_accessible_resources": ["loading.html","bu.png"] 


 }
```

Notice that the [background property](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) now contains an array of strings representing JavaScript files to be loaded (in the order specified) in to a dynamically generated background page.

I've also set the `minimum_chrome_version` property to 18 as manifest version 2 should only be used when targeting this version of Chrome and above.

Developers should now only really need to use background pages instead of scripts when they need to support older versions of Chrome.

## Edit

It just clicked that you're attempting to execute embedded JavaScript within your background page. Manifest version 2 introduces [Content Security Policies](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) which prohibit the execution of inline (e.g. `onclick="showDialog();"` and `href="javascript:void(0);"`) and embedded JavaScript. This is why your background.html won't work and why background.js will. You will also want to ensure your popup.html doesn't contain any embedded JavaScript. The best workaround (and generally best practice anyway) is to abstract all JavaScript into its own file (e.g. popup.js) which is referenced by the HTML file. For example;

```html
<script src="/popup.js"></script>
```

Comment: I relaised the mistake in the html and corrected it but it still does not work. I have no clue what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you please try changing the [match pattern](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html) you used in your manifest from `http://*/` to `http://*/*` as this could be the problem. This will need changed in the `content_scripts` and `permissions` properties. Can I assume that the code in your popup.html is wrapped in a `<script>` element? Finally, are you seeing any errors or abnormalities in either the popup or background page consoles?

Comment: I finally got it to work. I removed the background.html, replaced it with a background.js and added the backround.js as the default background page- THough i dont get why i background.html is not supported . Thanks a lot for the help -

Comment: That makes perfect sense now. Please see my updated answer for an explanation.

Comment: Okay. But can i get the function of document.getElementById('someidinpopup.html') in my background page Because right now it keeps throwing the null exception-|Error in event handler for 'undefined': TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"|

Comment: You want to look at [chrome.extension.getViews](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews) (and probably [chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage) out of interest) to do this. Here's an example of how I use it to manually close the popup window (in CoffeeScript); https://github.com/neocotic/template/blob/master/src/lib/background.coffee#L362